# New entry in junction table but avoid duplicate in table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates

I have three tables,

Table1 has id(pk) and name
Table2 has id(pk) and category
Table3 is a junction table and has id(pk) and two foreign keys: table1_id (pk from mentioned table1) and table2_id (pk from mentioned table2)

The form page has an input box (name), and a dropdown list that get's options from Table2.
When the form is submitted, the name is entered in Table1.name and Table3 gets populated with the id of the dropdown option and the id of the name entered.

All this is working as expected.

The scenario in which I'm looking for an answer is this:

In the form page, if the name entered already exists in Table1, but the combination of the dropdown and name is unique than something previously entered, I'd like the name **NOT to be** INSERTed in Table1, however the combination **to be** INSERTed in Table3

```
Table1
| id |   name   |
-----------------
| 1  |   John   |
| 2  |   Mark   |

Table2
| id | category |
-----------------
| 1  |   Red    |
| 2  |   Blue   |

Table3
| id | table1_id | table2_id |
------------------------------
| 1  |   1       |   1       |
| 2  |   1       |   2       |
```

Answer (score 0):

## Table1

```
"IF(
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM Table1
        WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'
    ) IS NOT NULL,
    '',
    (
        INSERT INTO Table1
        VALUES(NULL,'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'))
    ),''
);"
```

## Table3

```
"IF(
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM Table3
        WHERE table1_id='".(int)$_POST['table1_id']."'
        AND   table2_id='".(int)$_POST['table2_id']."'
    ) IS NOT NULL,
    '',
    (
        INSERT INTO Table3
        VALUES('".(int)$_POST['table1_id']."','".(int)$_POST['table2_id'])."'))
    ),
);"
```

I haven't tried this before, but I believe it'd work. Also, depending on your PHP code, the `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])` and `(int)$_POST['tableX_id']` bits may need to be a little different.

Comment: Not quite right, I mentioned a couple of conditions, one that involves inserting in Table3 as well.